# Editing a button text inside elementor CTA-element

Tags: css, wordpress, button, elementor

I use elementor to build a website right now and wanted to align the text inside the CTA-Button into the center. The "automatic" changes you can make in elementor to the Call-to-action end up aligning all the text, and I just want the text on the button to be centered. I used custom css before and ended up with this code:

```
.elementor.cta__button {text-align: center;}
```

but somehow it doesn't work (I've also tried putting selector in front of it but still no luck)

Does anyone have a solution for that? Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved it myself apparently I overedited the CTA and there was a bug because of a font I used

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).